# Get path of file from a SubGroup in project with Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, path, plist

I want to access the path of plist file

[image]

I am accessing path with following line

I can access when file is in root folder with following line

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: Constants.googleServiceFileName, ofType: "plist")
```

but when i move files in sub group and use following code its return nil

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: Constants.googleServiceFileName, ofType: "plist",inDirectory: "Firebase")
```

but it's return nil ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group in which you keep a resource in Xcode is not necessarily related to its final location in the bundle. Your file is probably still in the top level *Resources* directory.

If you want to be completely sure where the build puts your file, look for the build log in the Report Navigator, locate the "Copy " line and expand it using the button at the right hand edge. That will tell you exactly where it is.

[image: A copy resource line from the build log]

In the above, I have an Excel spreadsheet in the group *testData*. You can see that the build has put it in the top level *Resources* directory.

Comment: CopyPlistFile /Users/abdulwahab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IR-eiedbqishgzmbigoyzgobjx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TargitName.app/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist 

/Users/abdulwahab/Documents/Git\ Development/IR/IR/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist (in target 'TargitName' from project 'IR')

Its show that my file is in the right place ... right ??

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon It shows that it is not in a subdirectory called `Firebase` in the target. You should use the original code from before you moved the plist into the Firebase group.

Comment: yes you are right ... its working fine when i use the     
       `let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
          Constants.googleServiceFileName, ofType: "plist")`  .... but how to take it to the subdirectory ?... and 
    `let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
    Constants.googleServiceFileName, ofType: "plist",inDirectory: "Firebase")` 
this line work fine after that ?